# Jacobian of the matrix transformation $Y = X^T X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, jacobian

Take $Y=X^TX$, where $X$ is $d\times d$. The differential $\mathrm{d}Y$ can be computed as follows:

\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d}Y = \mathrm{d}(X^T)X + X^T\mathrm{d}(X)
\end{equation}

Using the property

\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{vec}(ABC) = (C^T\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}B
\end{equation}

where vec() denotes the [vectorization operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), this becomes

\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{dvec}(Y) = (X^T\otimes I_d)\mathrm{dvec}(X^T) + (I_d\otimes X^T)\mathrm{dvec}(X)
\end{equation}

To handle $\mathrm{dvec}(X^T)$, we will need the commutation matrix. The $mn\times mn$ commutation matrix $K_{mn}$ is defined to be the unique permutation matrix such that, for an $m\times n$ matrix $A$,

\begin{equation}
    K_{mn}\mathrm{vec}(A) = \mathrm{vec}(A^T)
\end{equation}

The commutation matrix also has the following properties (where $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $p\times q$):

\begin{equation}
K_{nm}K_{mn} = I_{mn} ~~~~~~~~~~\mathrm{and}~~~~~~~~~~ (A\otimes B)K_{nq} = K_{mp}(B\otimes A)
\end{equation}

Using these results, our differential becomes

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{dvec}(Y) = (K_{dd}+I_{d^2})(I_d\otimes X^T)\mathrm{dvec}(X)
\end{equation}

which further implies that

\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{d}Y = |(K_{dd}+I_{d^2})(I_d\otimes X^T)|\mathrm{d}X = 2^{d^2}\bigg|\frac{1}{2}(K_{dd}+I_{d^2})\bigg||X|^d \mathrm{d}X
\end{equation}

This is where my problem comes in. The matrix $M = \frac{1}{2}(K_{dd}+I_{d^2})$ is idempotent and not equal to the identity, so $|M|=0$. It doesn't seem correct that $\mathrm{d}Y$ would equal zero, so I must be misunderstanding something. Any help catching my error would be appreciated.

References:

- Mathai, A. M., *Jacobians of Matrix Transformation and Functions of Matrix Arguments*
- Abadir, K.M., Magnus, J.R., *Matrix Algebra*

Comment: What is the meaning of $\operatorname{vec}$?

Comment: Let $X=(x_{ij})$ be a $p\times q$ matrix and let the $j$-th column of $x$ be denoted by $x_{(j)}$. Then, $\mathrm{vec}(X)$ is the column vector formed by stacking each of the $x_{(j)}$. For example, if $X=\begin{pmatrix}
 a,b\\
 c,d
\end{pmatrix}$ then $(\mathrm{vec}(X))^T = (a,c,b,d)$

Comment: edit you post then

Comment: what is the tensor product $\otimes$ you are using?

Comment: It's the standard Kronecker product for matrices

Comment: Your differential isn't quite right
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\vecc{dY} &= \LR{I\otimes X^T}\vecc{dX}+ \LR{X^T\otimes I}\vecc{dX^T} \\
d\!\vecc{Y} &= \BR{\LR{I\otimes X^T}+\LR{X^T\otimes I}K}\,d\!\vecc{X} \\
}$$

Comment: Use $(A\otimes B)K = K(B\otimes A)$ to pull out a factor of $I\otimes X^T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qnq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$There is nothing wrong with your analysis, the determinant is zero. Here's another way to think about the problem.

Given a matrix $X$ with no special structure, construct the symmetric matrix
$Y=X^TX$

Now consider the Cholesky factorization (triangular factors)
$$\eqalign{
Y &= LL^T = U^TU \qiq U=L^T \qquad\qquad \\
}$$
or the Singular Value factorization (orthogonal factors)
$$\eqalign{
Y &= VDV^T = W^TW \qiq W = D^{1/2}V^T \\
}$$
or an Eigenvalue factorization...

There are many factorizations of the form $Y=M^TM\:$ but the factors are all very different. So while $Y$ is a function $X$, it is not correct to think of $X$ as a function of $Y$.

Looking at the vectorized differential in terms of the Jacobian matrix $J$
$$\eqalign{
y &= \vecc{Y},\quad x=\vecc{X} \qiq dy = J\:dx \\
}$$
It shouldn't be too surprising that $J^{-1}$ does not exist, since $x$ is not a function of $y$.

However, this does not mean that $J$ is equal to zero.

Comment: Correct me if I’m being silly, but doesn’t that the output of the map $X\mapsto X^{\top}X$ is (everywhere) contained in the subspace of symmetric matrices immediately imply that the derivative has (everywhere) rank $\leq d+\tfrac{d^{2}-d}{2}$ (which is strictly less than $d$ so long as $d>1$), and is thus (everywhere) singular (so long as $d>1$)?

Comment: @Rafi  Yes, that might be a better way to think about it.  The final conclusion is the same, i.e.  the Jacobian is singular.